# bootstrap thumbnail white space with no reason

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have random white space inside my website.

My HTML (Laravel) is build like this:

```
<ul class="thumbnails" style="max-width: 100%;">

        @foreach($img as $image)
            <li class="span2 thumbnail">
                <div class="overflow-hidden">
                    <img src="{{ Config::get('app.url') }}/{{ $image }}" />
                </div>
            </li>

        @endforeach

        </ul>
```

This is the output: [image: output]

And every time I refresh the page, there is another white space.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I believe you're having this issue because of the `margin-right` on the 5th `li`. I would check there first.

Comment: Post your rendered HTML and CSS.

Comment: This is the rendered code I have, but looped. It is always the same, exept the url. <li class="span2 thumbnail"><div class="overflow-hidden"><img src="http://rallypodium.tk/public/pictures/spiegels/TAC/Tielt 2011.JPG" /></div></li>

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read up on the [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) to understand why this is happening.

> Columns create gutters (gaps between column content) via padding. That padding is offset in rows for the first and last column via negative margin on .rows.

In other words, if you look at bootstrap.css:

```
.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

You can fix your code adding the `row` class to your `<ul>` element so you have:

```
<ul class="thumbnails row">
```

Or, just add the `margin-left` and `margin-right` properties.

Comment: @Mark I tried te both alone and combined, now I have something like this as output: http://prntscr.com/70ym80 This is the code I'm using: http://laravel.io/bin/jQWzG and the rendered code looks like this: http://laravel.io/bin/8KQoQ I took a look to the grid system of bootstrap, but I didn't find the solution there... :(

Answer (score 1):

am i correct that you want the thumbnails to line up 5 times, than start a new row of 5?

Then you have to build in a counter that closes a row, and start a new row:

**Beware of code:** i do not know laravel, went true documentation to write this, it could be wrong, main focus here is the idea i am giving you:

```
<ul class="thumbnails" style="max-width: 100%;">

<?php $i=0 ?>
@foreach($img as $image)
 <li class="span2 thumbnail">
  <div class="overflow-hidden">
   <img src="{{ Config::get('app.url') }}/{{ $image }}" />
  </div>
 </li>
<?php $i++ ?>
@if ($i === 5)
 </ul><ul class="thumbnails" style="max-width: 100%;">
@endif
@endforeach

</ul>
```

And be sure to read the answer by WEX, about the grid system.